# How to choose suitable X and Y coordinates for placing circles on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, algorithm, react-typescript

I'm designing a web app in which I can drag and drop circles anywhere in editor. I want to place/create a new circle on button click (ADD A ROW => can be seen in top left of image). Is there any efficient way to choose suitable X and Y coordinates because I'll be having maximum of 20 circles in editor. Ideally, I want them not to overlap each other.

[image: reference image]

Please don't tell me to use random X and Y coordinates. Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So far, I'm using useRef and useState for saving editor's width & height. Whenever Add a Row button is clicked, I get that width & height from the state and use it to make a new circle with random number * (width for x or height for y). It works but then again, I get overlapping circles. I'd love an algorithm for this.